# "Reserved namespace" error occurs when chaining named templates with "xsl:original" in XSLT-3.0

Tags: xslt-3.0

I'm trying to chain named templates in XSLT 3.0 using the "xsl:original" feature, but I get a reserved-name namespace error.

As an example, I use a named template `add-atts` that is defined in two included stylesheets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="root/line"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="line">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:call-template name="add-atts"/>  <!-- USED HERE -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:import href="add-foo.xsl"/>  <!-- DEFINED HERE -->
  <xsl:import href="add-bar.xsl"/>  <!-- DEFINED HERE -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first included stylesheet has a named template that adds a `@foo` attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0">

  <xsl:template name="add-atts">
    <xsl:attribute name="att1">foo</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The second included stylesheet has a named template of the same name (which takes precedence due to ordering) that adds a `@bar` attribute, then attempts to call the overridden template from the previous file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0">

  <xsl:template name="add-atts">
    <xsl:attribute name="att2">bar</xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:call-template name="xsl:original"/>  <!-- HERE -->
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I run this on the following input file

```
<root>
  <line>1</line>
  <line>2</line>
  <line>3</line>
</root>
```

I get the following error:

```
$ java -jar .../Saxon-HE-9.9.1-4.jar in.xml trans.xsl
Static error in xsl:call-template/@name on line 8 column 46 of add-bar.xsl:
  XTSE0080: Namespace prefix xsl refers to a reserved namespace
Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation
```

The `xsl:` namespace is declared, the XSLT version is set to 3.0, and the usage is the same as what's shown in [this example](https://www.oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/201307/msg00081.html) from the deprecated XSL-LIST mailing list. What am I missing?

(The actual intent is to chain named templates when creating plugins for the DITA Open Toolkit.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The feature exists in the context of the new XSLT 3 features of packages, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#refer-to-overridden. Neither the spec nor that thread you have linked to seem to introduce this feature in the context of simply `xsl:import`s.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality exists in the context of the new XSLT 3 feature of packages, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#refer-to-overridden. Neither the spec nor that thread you have linked to seem to introduce this functionality in the context of simply `xsl:import`s.

To give you an example on how this can be used in XSLT 3 with packages, suppose you have a first package

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:package 
    name="http://example.com/packages/ex1"
    package-version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:template name="add-atts" visibility="public">
        <xsl:attribute name="att1">foo</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>    

</xsl:package>
```

then you can write a second package overriding that named template and making use of `<xsl:call-template name="xsl:original"/>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:package 
    name="http://example.com/packages/ex2"
    package-version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:use-package name="http://example.com/packages/ex1">
        <xsl:override>
            <xsl:template name="add-atts" visibility="public">
                <xsl:attribute name="att2">bar</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:call-template name="xsl:original"/>
            </xsl:template>           
        </xsl:override>
    </xsl:use-package>

</xsl:package>
```

Finally you can use the second package:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0">

    <xsl:use-package name="http://example.com/packages/ex2"></xsl:use-package>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="root/line"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="line">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="add-atts"/>  <!-- USED HERE -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With Saxon from the command line, you would need to make sure you give the list of file names of the two packages with the `-lib` option e.g. `-lib:package1.xsl;package2.xsl` on Windows and `-lib:package1.xsl:package2.xsl` on Linux, when you run the main stylesheet.

Comment: This worked, thank you! I was able to run the example and see how it works. Your answer will be useful for others looking to implement chained named templates.